# How to generate a report for unit test result in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, unit-testing

How to generate a report for unit test result in Visual Studio 2022. And I used C# language and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` framework for testing these methods.

Answer (score -1):

To generate a report for unit test result in Visual Studio 2022, you can use the built-in test runner in Visual Studio. You can run your tests and generate a report by following these steps:

1. Open your test project in Visual Studio.
2. In the Test Explorer window, select the tests you want to run.
3. Right-click on the selected tests and choose "Run Selected Tests".
4. After the tests have completed, click on the "Test Results" tab.
5. In the "Test Results" tab, you can see the results of your tests.
6. To generate a report, right-click on the test results and choose "Export Test Results".

If you want to learn more about unit testing in Visual Studio 2022, you can check out Microsoft’s official documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/getting-started-with-unit-testing?view=vs-2022&tabs=dotnet%2Cmstest)

Comment: But no option 6 in my text explorer

Comment: If you are unable to find option 6 in your Test Explorer window, it might be because of different versions of Visual Studio. You can try to update your Visual Studio version. @DilshanDekumpitiya